# Protect wp-cron from hackers

Tags: wp-cron

I would like to get help on protecting wp-cron against hackers.

Set up: Lightsail Bitnami Apache server, headless Wordpress CMS, frontend is on AWS Amplify.

My wp-admin folder is protected with htpasswd, but my wp-cron can be accessed by hackers. If I protect the whole cms from the root, which is possible since the frontend is on Amplify, the wp-cron won't work. Alternatively I added some important cron tasks into crontab, but Wordfence has tons of cron job which I don't feel like I should copied them over to crontab. It's very important for Wordfence to be run in the backround to protect my cms.

Is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you've already checked the [WP documentation about hardening](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/hardening-wordpress/).

Comment: I'm sorry, but have you read it? Because I have read it and there is nothing regarding wp-cron.

Comment: In what way is wp-cron vulnerable?

Comment: Well @JacobPeattie, I don't really know apart from cross-site scripting. I am not a big tech person in this areas. You suggest that I don't need to protect it?

Comment: I can’t really imagine what wp-cron would have to do with cross site scripting.

Comment: Thanks. I believe you and I will close the question then.